# Login module in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm engaging in a log in module for my Access program. But I don't know much about it.

The uses log in their computers with windows logins, and in the database I have a table describing every login and their roles(worker, manager etc.).

What I want to do is when my program starts, it can auto detect the windows login, and according to the table, decides to hide some forms or reports.

Any suggestions? Thanks ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  Enter this outside of a procedure:

```
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
    "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
```

And enter this procedure:

```
Function GetUser() As String
    Dim cn As String, Userstr As String
    cn = String(1024, 0)
    If GetUserName(cn, 1024) <> 0 Then GetUser = Replace(cn, Chr(0), "")
End Function
```

Then GetUser() should give you the windows login name.  I use this in several Access 2003 Frontends running on XP machines and haven't had any problems with it.

(Side note: I actually got this code from Stack Overflow a long time ago, but I have no idea who gave it to me, so I can't give proper credit)

Comment: Thanks it works. But on WIN7, does it work? I don't have a computer with WIN7 at hand so cannot test

Comment: @darkjh, probably not.  If you're using a Windows 7 machine, it probably has Office 2007 or above, which uses VB.NET, not VBA. I don't think it would be very difficult to convert this code snippet to VB.NET, but that's a question for someone else to answer, not me.

Comment: It likely came from the Access Web, http://mvps.org/access/ , which is the FAQ site for the Usenet group comp.databases.ms-access.

Comment: Er, Office 2007 and later DO NOT use VB.NET -- they still use VBA. It is true that in O2007, some apps other than Access can utilize .NET components, and in O2010, the implication is that Access can, too, but VBA is still live for all Office applications. You do have to be careful about the long pointer type if you're running 64-bit Access on 64-bit Windows (i.e., you'll have to do a conditionally compiled version of your API call), but nobody should be running 64-bit Access.

Comment: Whoa, thanks for the correction! I must have misread something. +1 for you.